# Record is saved even when a custom validation fails Rails 3

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I'm working with rails 3.0.5, and I made a custom validation for my model, when I create or update a container record, the validation is effectively executed and add errors when it has to, but the record is still saved in database.

I've tested every step of the custom validation method and works fine.

Here is my model and custom validation:

```
class Container < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Comparable
  belongs_to :booking

  validates :booking, presence: true
  validates :kind, presence: true
  validates :dimension, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true }
  validates :retirement_location, presence: true
  validates :amount, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than_or_equal_to: 1 }
  validate :uniqueness_of_single_fields

  scope :group, lambda {|k,d| where('kind = ? and dimension = ?',k,d) }

  def self.to_hash
    {
      "kind" => self.kind.to_s,
      "dimension" => self.dimension.to_s,
      "retirement_location" => self.retirement_location.to_s
    }
  end

  def uniqueness_of_single_fields
    similar_containers = Container.joins(:booking).where('bookings.requirement_id = ? and containers.id != ?', booking.requirement.id, id)
    similar_containers = similar_containers.where(assigned_unit: assigned_unit, assigned_seal: assigned_seal)

    unless similar_containers.empty?
      errors.add(:base, "esa unidad y sello ya han sido asignados")
    end
  end

  def <=>(other)
    result = kind <=> other.kind
    result == 0 ? dimension <=> other.dimension : result
  end
end
```

P.S. I've checked previous questions, but none of then have the answer to this

I made a rspec test to try this

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Container do
  it 'should have a uniq combination assigned unit and seal for in a requirement' do
    requirement1 = Factory(:requirement, reference: 'abc123')
    requirement2 = Factory(:requirement, reference: 'qwerty')

        booking1 = Factory(:booking, reference: 'FOOBAR123', requirement: requirement1)
    booking2 = Factory(:booking, reference: 'FOOBAR456', requirement: requirement1)
    booking3 = Factory(:booking, reference: 'FOOBAR789', requirement: requirement2)

    container1 = Factory(:container, assigned_unit: 'foo1', assigned_seal: 'bar1', booking: booking1)
    container2 = Factory.build(:container, assigned_unit: 'foo1', assigned_seal: 'bar1', booking: booking2)
    container3 = Factory(:container, assigned_unit: 'foo1', assigned_seal: 'bar1', booking: booking3)

    container1.should be_valid
    container3.should be_valid

    puts container2.errors
    container2.save
    puts container2.inspect
    container2.should_not be_valid
    puts container2.errors.inspect
    container2.errors[:base].first.should == "esa unidad y sello ya han sido asignados"

    c = Requirement.new(client: 'foo')
    c.save
    puts c.errors
    puts c.inspect
  end
end
```

and the output is: (It passes when It should fail)

```
{}
#<Container id: 6, kind: "dry", dimension: 20, retirement_location: "sitrans", booking_id: 5, created_at: "2011-03-28 22:31:13", updated_at: "2011-03-28 22:31:13", load: "wine 2", assigned_unit: "foo1", assigned_seal: "bar1", temp_celsius: nil, temp_fahrenheit: nil, vent_percentage: nil, vent_cfm: nil, generator: nil, amount: 1>
{:base=>["esa unidad y sello ya han sido asignados"]}
{:service=>["Debe elegir un tipo de servicio"], :shipping_company=>["Debe haber una naviera relacionada con esta orden de servicio"]}
#<Requirement id: nil, client: "foo", service_id: nil, realization: nil, hour: nil, shipping_company_id: nil, description: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, reference: nil, state: "new">
.

Finished in 0.45293 seconds
1 example, 0 failures
```

Comment: Any error when you call `model.save!`  ?

Comment: Why `container2 = Factory.build(` and not `container2 = Factory(` ?

Comment: because it throws an exception I want the error be thrown later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're close, but you've been reading snippets rather than tutorials or documentation. If you reference the [Railscast Episode On Rails3 Validations](http://railscasts.com/episodes/211-validations-in-rails-3), then you'll see they recommend defining your own custom validator subclass, rather than sticking another function onto your model.

You might say Abstraction isn't required just because it's "more proper" or some such? Then check out the [API doc for Validations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations.html)

Here, they say "a minimal implementation" is like:

```
class Person
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name

  validates_each :first_name, :last_name do |record, attr, value|
    record.errors.add attr, 'starts with z.' if value.to_s[0] == ?z
  end
end
```

or

```
class Person
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  validates :instance_validations

  def instance_validations
    validates_with MyValidator
  end
end
```

Most important is the [API entry for the `validates` method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates), where they even suggest you define a custom Validator class inside your class/model:

```
class Film
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  class TitleValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
    def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
      record.errors[attribute] << "must start with 'the'" unless value =~ /\Athe/i
    end
  end

  validates :name, :title => true
end
```

Cheers!